# WPF navigation via buttons

Tags: wpf, button, navigation

Question: Is there a way to make a button behave like a hyperlink *inside of a user control?*

---

I've been searching around for a few days now and haven't found anyone who has addressed this. How do you use a button to navigate in a WPF application? Specifically how do you make a button inside of a user control navigate it's host frame? Bare in mind that User controls do not have direct access to the host frame. so simply:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(this.addressTextBox.Text));
```

won't work. I'm using user controls. If you are using only pages, this is the answer you are looking for, if you are using UserControls, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like a goof ball for answering my own question, but i figured it out at long last!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pg As Page = CType(GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(Me, GetType(Page)), Page)
    Dim newPage As %desired uri here% = New %desired uri here% 
    pg.NavigationService.Navigate(newPage)
End Sub

Private Function GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(ByVal startObject As DependencyObject, ByVal type As Type) As DependencyObject
    'Walk the visual tree to get the parent(ItemsControl)
    'of this control
    Dim parent As DependencyObject = startObject

    While (Not (parent) Is Nothing)
        If type.IsInstanceOfType(parent) Then
            Exit While
        Else
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent)
        End If

    End While
    Return parent
End Function
```

This function i found here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f8b02888-7e1f-42f4-83e5-448f2af3d207) will allow for the use of NavigationService inside of a user control.

~N

Answer (score 1):

Use the [NavigationService..::.Navigate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053.aspx):

```
void goButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(this.addressTextBox.Text));
}
```